# How to I allow direct write access to a directory under /home/username?

Tags: debian, permissions, chmod

For some reason after reinstalling **Debian 8 (LVM encrypted)** I need to
`sudo` for any writing command in certain directories of `/home/manuel/` directory (not even all of them!).

I tried `chmod a=awx [-R]` to allow write access to my user (which belongs to the sudoeur group) but nothing changed.

How do I allow **any** directory under /home/username to be directly **readable/writable/executable** when **my** user (username) is signed in?

**EDIT**:

ls -l /home/manuel/
returns

...

> drwxr-xr-x  4 root   root   4096 Jun  6 12:09 subdir # this is the directory I want to give my user full rwx access

...

Comment: /home/ is a place where all users home folders is put. My direct path to my home folder would be /home/roxto/ while yours should be /home/jeff/ et.c.

Comment: of course I meant /home/username. I'll fix the answer's body

Comment: can you please do `ls -l /home/manuel/`

Comment: quesions's body*

Comment: @roxto I updated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try,

```
chown manuel:manuel /home/manuel/subdir/
```

above command will give your account ownership over the folder `subdir`, if there's more directories owned by root under subdir (you can check with `ls -Rl /home/manuel/subdir/`) you could add the recursive option `-R` to the earlier `chown` command like this `chown -R manuel:manuel /home/manuel/subdir/`. That'll make all folders under `subdir` owned by `manuel`.